# NodeJS throw UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when i hanle error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to handle the error when the user intentionally entered the wrong objectId, but when I compressed the error in a function check objectID, I got this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: INVALID_ID

function check obejctID :

```
function checkObjectId(...ids) {
    ids.forEach(id => {
        const objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id);
        if (!objectId) throw new MyError('INVALID_ID',404);
    });
}
```

service :

```
static async updateAuthor(_id, content) {
    checkObjectId(_id);
    const author = await Author.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, content, { new: true });
    if (!author) throw new MyError('CAN_NOT_FIND_AUTHOR', 404);
    return author;
}
```

router :

```
    routerAuthor.put('/:_id',async (req, res) => {
        AuthorService.updateAuthor(req.params._id,req.body)
        .then(author => res.send({success : true, author}))
        .catch(res.onError);
    });
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.onError = function(error) {
        const body = { success: false, message: error.message };
        if (!error.statusCode) console.log(error);
        res.status(error.statusCode || 500).send(body);
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your code?

Comment: looks like your `checkObjectId` defined like `async function checkObjectId`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use try catch:

```
static async updateAuthor(_id, content) {
  try {
    checkObjectId(_id);
    const author = await Author.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, content, { new: true });
    if (!author) throw new MyError('CAN_NOT_FIND_AUTHOR', 404);
    return author;
  } catch (e) {
     throw new Error(e);
  } 
}
```